# Reloading a jstree without refreshing the page

Tags: jstree

I'm trying to reload a `jstree` without reloading or refreshing the page, the reload should happen `onclick` of a button, so when the button is clicked im calling

```
$("#tree-container").jstree('destroy'); 
//then calling the function that reads or renders the tree
```

that works fine when no tree is already rendered, however when a tree is already rendered and I click on the button I get this : **"cannot call method init of undefined."** the error occurs in the `jstree plugin`.

I even tried removing the container then re-appending it to it's parent container before calling the function that reads the tree

```
$("#tree-container").remove();

$('#parent-tree-container').append($('<div id="tree-container"></div>'));
//then called the function that reads/renders the tree
```

but that still didn't work. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This will make an ajax call to refresh the tree, but not the page it's contained in:

```
$.jstree._reference($("#tree-container")).refresh(-1);
```

That is the best method, but if you prefer, you can just rebuild the jstree over the initial div without destroying it first:

`$("#tree-container").jstree({` etc

Comment: I need to rebuild the tree because its content changes. the function that I use to build the tree has the building part you pointed. i.e $("#tree-container").jstree({ etc   I still get this : "cannot call method init of undefined." if an instance of the tree is already rendered.

Comment: You can use refresh even if it's content changes, that's what it's there for. Specify a flag in the jstree url if you need. Alos, edit your answer to add your tree declaration, not just the destroy part

Comment: Also possible: `$('#tree-container').jstree('refresh');` which is more the "jquery-way".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery 1.6.2?  If so, try a lower version - 1.6.1 should work. - [see here](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/42)